# How do I make a field mandatory if the previous field is set to yes?

Tags: javascript, conditional

I need some help with JavaScript code, please. In Salesforce Communities, I have a form that asks a question, if you answer yes, then more fields appear. I want to set it to if yes, those fields become mandatory.

This part works fine:

```
  <label for="export">Do you export?</label>
  <ui:inputSelect value="{!v.account.Export__c }" aura:id="export">
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="No" />
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="Yes" />
  </ui:inputSelect>

  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.account.Export__c == 'Yes'}">
```

I would like to make the below mandatory **only** if yes is selected:

```
    <label for="export-where">Where do you export?</label>
      <ui:inputSelect multiple="true" aura:id="export-where" value=" !v.account.Export_to_where__c}" change="{!c.handleExports}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 1" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 2" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 3" />
       </ui:inputSelect>

      <label for="export-what">What do you export?</label>
        <ui:inputTextArea aura:id="export-what" value="{!v.account.Export_what__c}" maxlength="32768" />                          
    </aura:if>
```

The below JavaScript works as all being mandatory. How do I change it so that when the Export_to_where__c question is filled it validates?

```
else if(getCurrentStep == 3){
    this.removeBorder(component, 'export');
    if((account.Export__c == 'No')) {
        return true;
    }
else{
    component.set("v.errorMessage","* Please fill all the required details");
   if(account.Export__c =='Yes' || account.Export_to_where__c == 'undefined' || account.Export_to_where__c == null || account.Export_to_where__c.trim() == '') {    
        this.addBorder(component, 'export-where');
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a simpler way below.
Example:

```
    <aura:application extends="force:slds">

        <aura:attribute name="val" type="String" default=""/>
        <aura:attribute name="textval" type="String" default=""/>

        <ui:inputSelect value="{!v.val }" aura:id="export">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="No" />
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Yes" />
        </ui:inputSelect>
        <br/>

<ui:inputSelect multiple="true" aura:id="export-where" value=" !v.account.Export_to_where__c}" required="{! v.val=='Yes'}">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 1" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 2" />
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="Option 3" />
       </ui:inputSelect>

        <ui:inputTextArea value="{!v.textval}" required="{! v.val=='Yes'}" label="text"/> 

    </aura:application>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like tit would only validate the yes or no, which isn't what I need.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear to me much, are you trying to make option group upon Yes/No question and if they click on option group.

Comment: If yes is selected, then 2 more fields appear. Those fields need to be mandatory ONLY if yes is chosen. If No is selected then the user continues on there journey.

Comment: I think my example answer above would help you to change the markup, and use less coding to achieve that. Not sure if you can use required="{!condition}" attribute to achieve it.Updated the example little bit more. Hope it helps. Cheers!